# Populating Plist to UITableView,Stored in Document Directory

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, plist, nsdocumentdirectory

I have plist stored in the `Document Directory`,how to call in `UITableView` if  it stored in Document Directory

[image: eneter image]
.
This is how I read from the plist.

In `ViewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

 NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"p.plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];

NSArray *valueArray = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

self.mySections = valueArray;

[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//Return the number of sections.
return [self.mySections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *dataInSection = [self.myData objectForKey:key];
return [dataInSection count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
}

-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return self.mySections;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

// Configure the cell...


NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];



NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];

NSDictionary *dataForSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *array=dataForSection.allKeys;

cell.textLabel.text = [[dataForSection allKeys] objectAtIndex:row];    
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[dataForSection valueForKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**
when i `NSlog` `valueArray` output is
    `( { pass = tryrt; title = tyr; }, 
    { pass = tryrt; title = tyr; }, 
    { pass = tryrt; title = tyr; }, { pass = tryrt546546; title = tyr; } )`

that means problem is in

`cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: You have an array of dictionaries at .plist.

Comment: ya..what changes required in code..help

Comment: This code doesn't look good itself, it assumes `self.myData` to be dictionary of arrays (sections) of dictionaries (rows) at `numberOfRowsInSection` but to be a dictionary of arrays of dictionaries of arrays of `NSString` at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it's very confusing. I think it will be easier if you decide the datasource structure first. If you want to read the given .plist into `self.myData` and use it, it's not clear how this data represents sections and rows. Maybe you could explain what are the `pass` and `title` values for. Also, can you change the .plist structure if needed ?

Comment: Like I have two textbox for these values I stored into the `pass` and `title`.now want to populate from plist and ya I can change but then need to make change to store data into plist

Comment: Well, I can imagine the `pass` values having the same paired `title` to be grouped into sections, so that the `title` value is used as the section title and `pass` values are rows text. Do you want to see something like this ?

Comment: ya write.I have edited my code..how i stored textbox data to plist

Comment: what is your requirement

Comment: @Rajneesh071 populating plist(above image) to uitableview

Comment: are you able to get data in valueArray, just nslog it

Comment: @Rajneesh071 its the same value which I entered ..i think problem is in cellForRowAtIndexPath, do u find any error

Comment: @A-Live problem is in cellForRowAtIndexPath,bcz I have slog to valuearray..its the same value which I entered in plist

Comment: just give me nslog(@"%@",valuearray);

Comment: value array (
        {
        pass = tryrt;
        title = tyr;
    },
        {
        pass = tryrt;
        title = tyr;
    },
        {
        pass = tryrt;
        title = tyr;
    },
        {
        pass = tryrt546546;
        title = tyr;
    }
)

Comment: @Rajneesh071 check its correct

Comment: I'm still not sure what is the problem, is there any exception or the table is empty ?

Comment: @A-Live ya table is empty from the above code..I am sure problem is in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: check my answer and then update me.. can you please explain me that what will your tableView look like..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//Return the number of sections.
return [self.mySections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSArray *allKeys = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section] allKeys];
return [allKeys count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

// Configure the cell...


NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSArray *allKeys = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section] allKeys];
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:0]];    
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:1]];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks! its working fine now.but problem is ...in tableview...each value is displaying twice ..means row 1 and duplicate value in row 2 for everyone

Comment: and if I give return 1; in numberofrowsinsection...then output is fine

Comment: enjoy now... that problem was because i don't know what exactly you want..:)]